# how to cancel/remove the audio filter when using google meet?

Tags: samsung, audio, android-11, volume, google-meet

I'm using a Samsung M21 with android 11. The audio quality decreases when im in a call on google meet. I use a wired earphone. this also affects other media like YouTube. the media volume also decreases. this issue didn't exist with older android versions(like android 7).
I can use my laptop where's no such issue, but it would be great if I could just use my phone.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no such filter. More likely, it is a problem with your device

Comment: Have you tried other wired earphones? Otherwise, there might be an issue with the headphone jack or its internal hardware. If possible, try wireless earphones too.

Comment: I have tried another wired earphone and also a blutooth (wireless) headphone. The issue persists.